# Bounded harmonic function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Can you please help me to prove that bounded harmonic function is constant?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: -1 No effort shown in this question at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If $u$ is a harmonic function then there exists a conjugate function $v$ and an analytic function $f=u+iv$. Thus $\exp(f)$ is bounded,  applying the Liouville's Theorem shows that $\exp(f)$  is constant.It's easy to prove that $f$  is constant, as well as $u$.

Comment: How do we know that $exp(f)$ is bounded?

Comment: @fioreb:How can you say,"If $u$ is a harmonic function then there exists a conjugate function $v$ and an  analytic function $f=u+iv $"?

Comment: @PKStyles... It seems fioreb assumes we are in dimension $2$, which the OP never said.

Answer (score 27):

E. Nelson, "A Proof of Liouville's Theorem", *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **12** (1961) 995

9 lines long. Not the shortest paper ever, but maximizes importance/length

> [image]

...

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2034412

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville.27s_theorem

Edward Nelson's paper is freely and legally available here:

$\bullet\ $ [pdf file](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4.pdf),

$\bullet\ $ [html page](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0259149-4/home.html).

Comment: Dear GEdgar: I hope you don't mind my edit. (+1)

Comment: Very nice and short proof.

Comment: nice proof, without a single formula.