# Finding bounded harmonic function on upper half-plane with Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I have been asked to find a bounded function $u(z)$ that is harmonic on $\Omega= \{z\in\mathbb{C}|\,|z|>1\,,\Im(z)>0\}$ that satisfies
\begin{equation}
u(z)=\begin{cases} 1\quad z\in\mathbb{R},|z|>1\\0\quad |z|=1,\Im(z)>0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Now i have been able to find a conformal map from $\Omega$ to the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}=\{z|\Im(z)>0\}$, namely $F(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}$. Then the problem reduces to finding a bounded harmonic function on the upper half-plane that satisfies
\begin{equation}
u(x,0)=\begin{cases} 1\quad x\in[-2,2] \\0\quad x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus[-2,2].
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

My first question: is there another conformal map $\phi$ that maps $[-2,2]$ to the vertical line $\Re(z)=1$ and that maps $\mathbb{R}\setminus[-2,2]$ to another vertical line $\Re(z)=0$. Because in that case I can find the correct harmonic function: $u(z)=\Re(\phi(F(z)))$

My second question: I saw here, [Bounded harmonic function is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103249/bounded-harmonic-function-is-constant), that a bounded harmonic function is a constant but clearly a constant function does not satisfy the boundary conditions so is it even possible to find the correct harmonic function?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are leaving out continuity assumptions on the boundary.

Comment: Because of the discontinuity at $z = 1$, your harmonic function will not be bounded there. It has to have an essential singularity at $1$ to exist at all.

Comment: Does the problem has a solution if the condition of boundedness is omitted? Or only bounded on $\Omega$ and not on whole $\bar{\Omega}$?